# Complex MYSQL trigger

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger in `mysql` that will populate a new table (customers) when another table (wp_usermeta) is populated. I know this can be bad design, but I'm in a situation where the `wp_usermeta` won't always be populated, and I need to make sure that `customers` always has the data I need.

To do this, I figured that creating a trigger would be the best way to accomplish this, but it isn't working, at all.

Here is what I have:

```
CREATE       TRIGGER `update_customers` AFTER INSERT ON `wp_usermeta`
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO test_customers
SET test_customers.first_name = new.meta_value;

END
```

I did this just to try and copy the `wp_usermeta` data over to the `customer` table, but that didn't work. The trigger was accepted by `mysql` but nothing happened when I added data to the `wp_usermeta` table.

One of the problems I'm having with this, is that I only want things like first name, last name, address, etc., to be populated into the `customers` database. The `wp_usermeta` table looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the table is set up with key/value pairs. So the issue I'm having is getting the `wp_usermeta.first_name` to transfer to the `customers.first_name`.

I don't have much experience with this type of thing, or databases in general.

Here is another query that I tried:

```
TRIGGER `update_customers` AFTER INSERT ON `wp_usermeta`
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO test_customers SET test_customers.first_name = wp_usermeta.meta_value WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key == first_name;

END
```

But that didn't work either. If someone could explain how to determine if the `meta_key` equals `first_name` to then apply the corresponding `wp_usermeta.meta_value` value to the `customers.first_name` table, that would be great.

I'm also open to suggestions if a trigger isn't the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `update_customers` AFTER INSERT ON `wp_usermeta`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF NEW.meta_key = 'first_name' AND NEW.meta_value IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO test_customers(first_name) Values(NEW.meta_value);
  END IF;
END;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cace/1)</kbd>

Comment: This allowed me to set the trigger, but when I run it, the `first_name` field doesn't get set in the `wp_usermeta` table, is this expected?

Comment: This trigger only gets called whenever you do an insert into wp_usermeta and first_name is different than null. What are you trying to accomplish that isn't working?

Comment: When I ran it, it created the new row in the `test_customer` table, but didn't get the value passed in. I may have a typo or something. Thank you very much!!! I think this will work for me!! Great answer btw :)

Comment: Are you saying that one record is inserted into test_customer when you do an insert in wp_usermeta but the value in test_customer is null?

Comment: Yes, more specifically the `first_name` value is null. It creates the new row, but doesn't seem to transfer the value of the first name. I've checked the variables and everything, making sure that everything is correct, but it doesn't seem to pass the value into the new table.

Comment: Null is impossible because the trigger is doing that validation. You might have spaces or something like that that looks like null. What is the value for first_name in wp_usermeta?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39573/discussion-between-blaine-and-filipe-silva)